# '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to download URL xlsx and storage an specific directory but I've got the follow message error:

> '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to
> get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))

Follow my python 3 code bellow:

```
import requests
dls = ('https://git.aneel.gov.br/publico/centralconteudo/-/raw/main/relatorioseindicadores/geracao/BD_SIGA.xlsx?')
resp = requests.get(dls)
with open(r'C:\Users\Lucas\output\aneltest.xls', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(resp.content)
```

How could I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Could you be wanting to use `urllib.request.urlopen` instead?

Comment: I've used : resp = requests.get(dls,verify=False) and it works fine now